# How to assign a resource with two units to the task?

Tags: ms-project, resources, ms-project-2016

I want to assign a resource -Excavator- to a task -Task#1 : duration = 4 month- :
2 units in first 2 months and 5 units in second 2 months.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you have 5 (five) excavators? And that you want to assign 2 (two) excavators for the first 2 (two) months of the Task#1 and the you want to assign the 5 (five) excavators for the second 2 (two) months of Task#1?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it. But first, make sure Excavator is a work resource (not a material resource) and its max. availability is 500% (to represent five available units).

*First way (easy one)*:

- Add two 2-month subtasks to Task 1: Task 2 and Task 3. Make Task 2
  the predecessor of Task 3.
- Assign Excavator to Task 2 at 200%.
- Assign Excavator to Task 3 at 500%.

*Second way (a little harder). Use this if you want to have only one task*:

- Assign Excavator to Task 1.
- Use an assignment view (either "Task Usage" or "Resource Usage").
- In the right pane, modify daily work from 8 hours to 16 hours. Do this for the first two months (yes, it will be somewhat tedious).
- Then, modify daily work from 8 hours to 40 hours the remaining two months.

Actually, I have found a third way to do it:

- Create five resources (Excavator 1, Excavator 2, etc).
- Assign the five excavators to Task 1.
- Use an assignment view ("Task Usage" or "Resource Usage").
- Change the Excavator 3 assignment (by double-clicking its row) and set the start date of the assignment two months after the Task 1 start date (maybe you should also have to change the assignment total work hours to half its value).
- Repeat for Excavator 4 and Excavator 5.

At the end, Excavator 1 and 2 should work the full task duration, and Excavator 3, 4, and 5 should work only during the second half of the Task.

Hope this helps. Greetings.